# Contact Ringtone set but android.process.phone killed when that contact calls

Tags: android

I am trying to set a ringtone(mp3 file) stored on my `/storage/sdcard0/Ringtones`  to a contact I wish. On running the app, the ringtone gets saved and I can see it listed when I open that contact. However, when that contact calls.

I do not get the call and the below message appears on my screen `: process com.android.phone stops.`
Below is the code which I am using to set ringtone to a contact -

```
   Nb: K is the File object which has the filename and path for the .mp3 clip  

   String str1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));

   Uri localUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, str1);

   ContentValues localContentValues = new ContentValues();

   localContentValues.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactId);

   localContentValues.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.CUSTOM_RINGTONE, k.getAbsolutePath());

   getContentResolver().update(localUri, localContentValues, null, null);
```

Logcat error when contact calls :

```
01-16 15:27:09.632: E/AndroidRuntime(24282): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-16 15:27:09.632: E/AndroidRuntime(24282): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-16 15:27:09.632: E/AndroidRuntime(24282):    at com.android.phone.Ringer.isValidRingtoneURI(Ringer.java:742)
01-16 15:27:09.632: E/AndroidRuntime(24282):    at com.android.phone.CallNotifier.onQueryComplete(CallNotifier.java:2079)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide Uri rather than absolute path (see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactOptionsColumns.html#CUSTOM_RINGTONE)):

```
Uri uriOfRt = Uri.fromFile(new File( k.getAbsolutePath()));    
localContentValues.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.CUSTOM_RINGTONE, uriOfRt);
```

Comment: ContentValues.put(String, Uri); doesn't exist. The correct thing would be uriOfRt.toString()